# Don't understand Matlab generated plot command

Tags: matlab

I'm new at Matlab and am exploring the tools in R2011a. I was able to successfully plot x vs sin(x) by selecting variables in the Workspace (upper-right subwindow) and pressing the plot(x,y) button, like so:

```
x = 0:0.01:2*pi;
y = sin(x);
```

[image: Selected x and y variables, then pressed plot(x,y)]

Apparently pressing the plot(x,y) button generates the following command, which I copied and pasted from the command window:

```
plot(x,y,'DisplayName','y vs. x','XDataSource','x','YDataSource','y');figure(gcf)
```

Can someone explain what the above command does? I did "doc plot" (using Matlab 2011a), and the resulting possible parameter options are listed below. Which one matches the above plot command, and how would I have figured that out?

```
plot(Y)
plot(X1,Y1,...,Xn,Yn)
plot(X1,Y1,LineSpec,...,Xn,Yn,LineSpec)
plot(X1,Y1,LineSpec,'PropertyName',PropertyValue)
plot(axes_handle,X1,Y1,LineSpec,'PropertyName',PropertyValue)
h = plot(X1,Y1,LineSpec,'PropertyName',PropertyValue)
```

Also, what does `figure(gcf)` in the generated command do?

Comment: You searched for `plot`, why didn't search for `gcf` then? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gcf.html

Comment: @natan, I'd say that's because `gcf` is passed as a param, so it's not quite obvious that it is a `current figure handle` which can be googled (for me, at least).

Comment: I thought it was some global variable that wasn't visible in my workspace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax that your command uses is the 4th in the list.

```
plot(x,y, [LineSpec,] 'property1', value1, 'property2', value2, 'property3', value3);
```

To get going with a graph the second form is often all you need:

```
x = 0:0.001:pi;
y = sin(x);
plot(x,y)
```

if you omit `x`, the values are implied to be the integers `1:len(y)`, which is sometimes sufficient, but not ideal in this case.

The `figure(H)` command either creates a figure window, or if the figure with handle `H` already exists, simply gives that figure the focus (which will bring it into view if it was hidden behind other windows, for instance).

The `LineSpec` can be used to modify the appearance of lines, e.g. how they are colored or whether the line is solid or dashed.  For example, `'r--x'` makes a dashed red line with crosses as markers (on each of the data points).  If this is omitted the default values are taken (a blue solid line with no markers).

For more advanced settings, the linespec can also include property, value pairs, but this complicates matters a bit as they have become generic property,value settings and thus can appear either with the `LineSpec` or with the `'PropertyName',PropertyValue` part.  So

```
plot(x,y, 'r--x', 'linewidth', 3, 'DisplayName', 'sin x')
plot(x,y, 'r--x', 'DisplayName', 'sin x', 'linewidth', 3)
```

are both valid and have the same effect of producing a thicker line, whereas

```
plot(x,y, 'linewidth', 3, 'DisplayName', 'sin x', 'r--x')
```

is invalid because the `LineSpec` comes after some property, value settings.

In general, try typing `help <command>` or `doc <command>` in the command window to try to better understand a particular function, or if you don't know exactly what the function might be called, try `lookfor <keyword>` (e.g.  `lookfor filter` will the functions relating to filtering).

**Edit:** the other properties set in this case are

- 'DisplayName'
- 'XDataSource'
- 'YDataSource'

The legend string will be shown next to the line for this plot. To show the legend (assuming the data above):

```
plot(x,y,'DisplayName', 'sin x');
legend toggle
```

Setting the data sources can be useful if you are making linked plots.
(see [online documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/data_analysis/making-graphs-responsive-with-data-linking.html)).

The help pages for `figure` and `figure properties` provide comprehensive details of all the properties a figure can take; and see `lineseries properties` for properties of the individual lines within a figure.

**Edit 2:** added explanation of linespec above.

Comment: What are the other arguments of the generated plot() command used for, namely 'DisplayName','y vs. x','XDataSource','x','YDataSource','y'? Are these the properties and values? How would I figure that out?

Comment: You say the generated plot command is the 4th in the list, but the 4th in the list is of the syntax: plot(X1, Y1, LineSpec, 'PropertyName', PropertyValue). What happened to the LineSpec? Is that optional?

Comment: You also mentioned that 'DisplayName' is in the docs for 'figure properties'. It's actually in 'Lineseries properties'.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, & well spotted error @stackoverflowuser2010.  I've updated the answer with explanation re: linespec.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure which MATLAB version you use, but `doc plot` has the above Syntax versions in R2011b and R2012b:

```
plot(Y)
plot(X1,Y1,...,Xn,Yn)
plot(X1,Y1,LineSpec,...,Xn,Yn,LineSpec)
plot(...,'PropertyName',PropertyValue,...)
plot(axes_handle,...)
h = plot(...)
```

http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/plot.html

This explains why it is allowed to "leave out" `LineSpec`: the pairs of `PropertyName`, `PropertyValue` can be placed anywhere in the paramter list. So technically your syntax is a combination of the second and the forth in this list -- and your `doc plot` version is not grammatically correct, true.

I believe that your other questions were already answered by Bonlenfum.

Comment: I'm using R2011a. But at any rate, neither your nor my documentation clearly state that LineSpec is optional. In the other typical languages and documentation, optional arguments are denoted with square brackets, e.g. [LineSpec].

Comment: `LineSpec` _is_ optional, because the second syntax does not include it and `...` means that any other parameters (e.g. `'PropertyName',PropertyValue`) can take up that place.